# Retrieve all duplicate data and delete unduplicated data Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the following table, for example

```
|----|-------------|-----|-----|--------------------|
| id |address      | log | lat | timestamp          |
|----|-------------|-----|-----|--------------------|
| 1  | New York    |14.20|0.22 |2019-10-21 14:00:01 |
| 2  | New York    |14.20|0.22 |2019-10-21 14:00:01 |
| 3  | New York    |14.20|0.22 |2019-10-21 14:00:01 |
| 4  | Italy       |10.36|0.75 |2019-10-21 14:00:01 |
| 5  | Spain       |10.36|0.75 |2019-10-21 14:00:01 |
| 6  | London      |10.36|0.75 |2019-10-21 14:00:01 |
|----|-------------|-----|-----|--------------------|
```

And for a select one, I want to have an array of data only with the duplicate ones.
That is, id 1 New York and its data, id 2 New York and its data, id 3 New York and its data and the rest of Italy, Madrid and London should be deleted because they are not duplicates
an item is duplicated if it appears more than once

I tried this

```
Address::groupBy('address')->having(DB::raw('count(*)'), ">", "1")->select('address')->get();
```

But all my addresses are taken over
How do I get my duplicates back into an array?

Comment: if you want a single record then use `group_by`, you can add expected output in question.

Comment: why not select distinct values using laravels distinct() then use those ids to bulk delete them?

Comment: I don`t know to use distinct

Comment: distinct wouldn't work. It would still include one of the duplicated rows (result set would have ids 1, 4, 5, 6). groupby / having is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

```
--returns rows with ids 4, 5, 6
SELECT id, address, COUNT(address)
FROM addresses
GROUP BY (address)
HAVING COUNT(address) = 1 --unduplicated only
ORDER BY id
```

This query should give you all **unduplicated** addresses with their id and address.

```
--returns rows with ids 1
SELECT id, address, COUNT(address)
FROM addresses
GROUP BY (address)
HAVING COUNT(address) > 1 --duplicated only
ORDER BY id
```

This query should give you all **duplicated** addresses with their id and address.

```php
// first query using the query builder
$unduplicated = Address::query()
    ->select('id', 'address')
    ->selectRaw('count(address) as count')
    ->groupBy('address')
    ->havingRaw('count(address) = 1')
    ->get();
```

Now, to delete all those unduplicated records there are 2 main options:

#### Option 1: bulk delete. Will not call eloquent events

```php
Address::query()->whereIn('id', $unduplicated->pluck('id'))->delete();
```

#### Option 2: delete one by one. Calls eloquent events.

This can be achieved in a lot of different ways:

```php
// using a Closure
$unduplicated->each(function ($address) {
    $address->delete();
});
```

```php
// using a Short Closure
$unduplicated->each(fn($address) => $address->delete());
```

```php
// using a high order collection
$unduplicated->each->delete();
```

```php
// using model's static destroy method
Address::destroy($unduplicated->pluck('id'));
```